# How to properly reference cells to avoid REF error when modify them

Tags: google-sheets

I have this spreadsheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nQzpJ1cOT8kdo-b_vFFoSIHyLMhqd__Cv4SipncVTnA/edit?usp=sharing

In Sheet 2:

```
   A       B       C       D 
col1    col2    col3    col4
   1       2       3       4
   2       4       6       8
   1       3       5       7
```

Then I want to copy all these numbers in Sheet1, so in Sheet 1 I have this formula in the cell A3:

A3:  `=IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&B2&"'!A2:O"),"")`

Where in B2 of Sheet1 I have the string "Sheet2".

Everything works fine. However, If I try to modify one of the cells which is referenced in Sheet1 (for example B3) I get

```
#REF error
```

Why is this and How can I avoid it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's because the range you selected to import from other sheet is **A2:O** which includes empty cells. to resolve it you can use dynamic **`ARRAY_CONSTRAIN`** and skip the empty cells with **`COUNTA`** like:

```
=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&B2&"'!A2:O"), ), 
 COUNTA(Sheet2!A2:A), COUNTA(Sheet2!A2:2))
```

to modify **B3** on **Sheet1** you will need to go in **Sheet2** and modify it there because those data are only "visually" imported from another sheet. eg. when you modify cell **B3** then cell **B3** is no longer empty and the stuff you want to import has no space to be enrolled (it can be enrolled only on empty cells)

Comment: I want to avoid using the name "Sheet2" directly. When I try to use  INDIRECT inside COUNTA I get an error

Comment: use: `=ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IFERROR(INDIRECT("'"&B2&"'!A2:O"), ), COUNTA(INDIRECT(B2&"!A2:A")), COUNTA(INDIRECT(B2&"!A2:2")))`